# Kendo UI TreeListDatasource Remote Data On Demand Id is null

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

I'm using the Kendo TreeList component and trying to do on demand remote data. This is what the datasource looks like:

```
 dsLocations = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: baseUrl + "getsuggestedorganizationlocations?oid=" + $("#Id").val(),
            dataType: "json"
        },

        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "Id",
                parentId: "ParentId",
                fields: {
                    Id: { type: "number", nullable: false },
                    ParentId: { field: "ParentId", nullable: true }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This is how the TreeList component is configured:

```
$("#suggestedLocations").kendoTreeList({
    dataSource: dsLocations,
    columns: [
        { field: "Name", expandable: true, title: "Location", width: 250 },
        { field: "Selected", title: "Selected" }
    ]
});
```

And this is what the data coming from the server looks like for the root:

```
[{"Id":5,"ParentId":null,"Selected":true,"hasChildren":true,"Name":"Kitchen"}]
```

When I expand the node to retrieve the children, the "id" in the querystring passed to the server is empty.

[image: Empty id]

If I change my model coming from the server to:

```
[{"id":5,"parentId":null,"Selected":true,"hasChildren":true,Name":"Kitchen"}]
```

Where the id and parentId are lower case, it works. My understanding is that the schema configuration is suppose to map that. What and I missing?

I'm using Kendo 2016.3.914

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I had placed the schema setting inside the transport config. Here is what it should be:

```
dsLocations = new kendo.data.TreeListDataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: _organizeApp.baseUrl + "getsuggestedorganizationlocations?oid=" + $("#Id").val(),
            dataType: "json"
        }

    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "Id",
            parentId: "ParentId",
            fields: {
                Id: { field: "Id", type: "number", nullable: false },
                ParentId: { field: "ParentId", nullable: true },

            }
        }
    }
});
```